# SQL Server CONCAT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to draw a statement like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(street_name, ' ', street_number) as 'street_detail' 
FROM geo_map 
WHERE CONCAT(street_name, ' ', street_number) LIKE '%'
```

My table is something like this

```
postal_code int
building_name nchar(200)
street_number nchar(60)
street_name nchar(120)
```

The result I get was just the street name, less the street number, although my street number have value, any idea what's went wrong in my concat.

I am using SQL Server

Comment: Perhaps the issue is how you are reading the value.

Comment: Why are these columns `nchar` and not `nvarchar`? I suspect you are looking at the results in grid mode and all the trailing spaces in `street_name` are pushing `street_number` off the screen to the right...

Comment: building_name nchar(200) - eeeeek!

Comment: Can you confirm that every row has street_number value?
`WHERE CONCAT(street_name, ' ', street_number) LIKE '%'` does not filter out rows that have NULL street_number if the rows have street_name values

Comment: What are you using where clause .. what you want to filter ? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to use `NVARCHAR(...)` instead of `NCHAR(...)` types for storing information like what you have. The reason is that for `NCHAR(...)` types, strings are padded with trailing spaces to fill the whole length of the field.

A string in an `NCHAR(200)` field is *always* 200 characters wide. The concatenation of `street_name`, a space and the `street_number` will be 261 characters wide. The building number will appear on the 202nd character in the concatenation.

Perhaps you are not seeing a street number in your concatenation because your display field (in your program, SSMS, webpage, ...) just isn't wide enough.

Now with storing your street name in an `NVARCHAR(200)` and pretty much all other related information in `NVARCHAR(...)` fields, you would not have that problem. Strings stored in those fields are *not* padded with trailing spaces, and you would see your street number at the place you expected in your concatenation.